# How do I get the AVG of multiple GROUPs, by the Parent's table ID in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, average

I'm having difficulties creating a query to pull a certain result set from a MySQL database. The reason I'm stumbling around is possibly because I'm uncertain on how to ask the question. If there is something I have missed out, please leave a comment so that I can adjust the question to better reflect what I am trying to achieve.

What I have is 3 tables: results, answers and sections.

results has some data and has multiple answers.

each answer has a section_id.

To get all my answers and results I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM answers AS a
JOIN results AS r ON r.id = a.result_id
JOIN sections AS s ON s.id = r.section_id
```

How do I get the AVG of each section by result_id?

Example:

```
results:
id
1
2

answers:
id, result_id, sectionId, sum
1, 1, 1, 5
2, 1, 1, 8
3, 1, 2, 5
4, 1, 2, 7
5, 1, 2, 5
6, 2, 1, 5
7, 2, 1, 5
8, 2, 1, 8
9, 2, 2, 7

sections:
id, name
1, "test1"
2, "test2"
```

Expected results:

```
resultId, sectionId, avg
1, 1, 6.5
1, 2, 5.7
2, 1, 6
2, 2, 7
```

Comment: I'm trying to get an average that is dependent on both the result_id and the section_id. At the moment it adds the sum for all result_id's. I need this to also cattier for the section_id's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a group by clause:

```
SELECT r.result_id, s.section_id, avg(sum)
FROM answers AS a
JOIN results AS r ON r.id = a.result_id
JOIN sections AS s ON s.id = r.section_id
GROUP BY r.result_id, s.section_id
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
SELECT a.id, b.sectionID, avg(`sum`) TotalAverage
FROM results a INNER JOIN answers b on a.id = b.resultID
    INNER JOIN sections c on b.sectionID = c.id
GROUP BY a.id, b.sectionID
```

PS: you should add a backtick in column `SUM` of table `answers` because `SUM` is a [RESERVED WORD in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT result_id, sectionId, AVG(`sum`) AS `avg` FROM answers GROUP BY result_id, sectionId;
```